# Application of trigonometry in a momentum conservation problem.

Tags: trigonometry, physics

> A particle of mass m is made to move with uniform sped v along the perimeter of a regular polygon of $2n$ sides. The magnitude of impulse applied at each corner of the polygon is:

$\mathbb {Impulse} = \vec{p_f}-\vec{p_i} $

I assumed the particle to be moving on the top edge of a regular hexagon. Here's my diagram: 
[image]

Now, when the particle moves to the other edge, it still has speed v but velocity vector is split into two components : $v\cos\theta \hat{i}- v\sin\theta\hat{j}$

which gives $\Delta vec{p} = mv\cos\theta \hat{i}- mv\sin\theta\hat{j} - mv\hat{i}$

$||\vec{\Delta p}||= \sqrt{m^2v^2\cos^2\theta +m^2v^2 - 2mv^2\cos^2\theta+m^2v^2\sin^2\theta} \\ = mv(\sqrt{2(1-cos\theta)}) $

Now, it's clear that $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}- \dfrac{\pi}{2n}  \\ \implies ||\vec{\Delta p}||= mv\sqrt{(2(1- \sin \dfrac{\pi}{2n}))}$

But answer given is: $2mv\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2n}$

Where have I gone wrong? [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B(2(1-%20%5Csin%20%7B%5Cpi%2F2n))%7D) doesn't simply my result too.

Comment: The blue angles ($\theta$) in figure are not in general equal!

Comment: Why @samjoe? ..

Comment: Consider octagon if you need a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that exterior angles of any polygon sum up to $2\pi$. Then each exterior angle of this $2n$-gon will be $\dfrac{\pi}{n}$. Then the change in momentum vector will have an angle $\theta=\pi-\frac{\pi}{n}$. This is the angle between *blue* and *red* vectors shown below:

[image]

Resolve along and perpendicular the angular bisector of this angle (*grey line*). Components along *grey line* add up, while components along *black line* cancel. So the answer is simply

$$\begin{align}\Delta p &= 2 mv \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\ 
&= 2 mv \cos\left(\frac{\pi-\tfrac{\pi}{n}}{2}\right)\\
 &= 2 mv \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: I also have $\theta = \dfrac{\pi - \pi/n}{2}$

Comment: Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: @Abcd Did you consider taking an octagon? You will notice the red horizontal line in your figure is not in general parallel to the topmost side..

Comment: Please show your calculations at least.

Comment: @Abcd Hopefully clears up a bit ..